# Jaxlib pip installation failure

Tags: python, windows, pip, jax

From the command line, I've tried following this installation [tutorial](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer.html#building-from-source) I'd like to avoid building from source if at all possible. Currently, I'm not sure what the issue is. Could anyone verify that they get the same/different response when trying to install Jaxlib?

For awareness, Jax installed fine without any issues, but some supporting components are found in Jaxlib which is installed separately.

```
C:\Users\john.smith>pip install jaxlib
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jaxlib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jaxlib
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you are using Windows. JAX currently does not provide `jaxlib` builds for Windows (see [google/jax#438](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/438)) though there is work in progress to rectify this; see [google/jax#4843](https://github.com/google/jax/pull/4843).

There are some [comments](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/438#issuecomment-668523185) in the above issue that suggest a possible approach to build jaxlib for Windows if you wish to build it yourself.